# The display of my dropdown menus are quite not working

Tags: javascript, css, function, drop-down-menu

I have javascript function where if values "abc", "abcd" or "abcde" has been chosen from the dropdown menu "optionDrop", then display the other dropdown menu "numberDrop", else output "N/A". The problem is that the "numberDrop" down menu is not appearing at all. What have I done wrong?

Below is javascript function:

```
      function getDropDown() {
         var optionDrop = document.getElementsByName("optionDrop");
        var noOfAnswers = document.getElementById("noOfAnswers");
        var numberDrop = document.getElementsByName("numberDrop");

    if (optionDrop.value = "abc" || optionDrop.value = "abcd" || optionDrop.value = "abcde"){
numberDrop.style.display = "block";
    }else{
                     noOfAnswers.innerHTML = "N/A";
    }

                }
```

Below is html dropdown menus is form:

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >
<table id="middleDetails" border="1">

<tr>
    <td>Option Type:</td> 

 <td>
        <select name="optionDrop" onClick="getDropDown()">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="abc">ABC</option>
<option value="abcd">ABCD</option>
<option value="abcde">ABCDE</option>
<option value="trueorfalse">True or False</option>
<option value="yesorno">Yes or No</option>
</select>
    </td>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>

<td>Number of Answers:</td>
<td id="noOfAnswers">
<select name="numberDrop" id="numberDropId">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

CSS code:

```
            /*css for QandATable.php*/

#numberDropId{
                display:none;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (optionDrop.value === "abc")
```

=== is exact match of same type. So it would have to match abc. = is for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript function as bellow.

```
  function getDropDown() {
         var optionDrop = document.getElementsByName("optionDrop");
        var noOfAnswers = document.getElementsByName("noOfAnswers");
        var numberDrop = document.getElementsByName("numberDrop");
    if (optionDrop[0].value == "abc" || optionDrop[0].value == "abcd" || optionDrop[0].value == "abcde"){
numberDrop[0].style.display = "block";
    }else{
                     noOfAnswers.innerHTML = "N/A";
    }

                }
```

Good luck.

Prasad